# dotnet core authorize always redirect to identity default login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I create custom login page in `pages/login.cshtml`, and also i set `[authorize]` config in `startup.cs` to redirect to `/login`, but it keep redirect to `Identity/Account/Login`.

this is my startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings.
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                // Lockout settings.
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings.
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            });



            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

                options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Dashboards/Dashboard1", "");
                    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Login");
                });


        }
```

I already specify `loginpath = "/login"`, but it always back to identity default page, why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this issue, try `services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>` like

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Dashboards/Dashboard1", "");
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Login");
    });
services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
    opt => {
        //configure your other properties
        opt.LoginPath = "/Login";
    });
```

Comment: @yozawiratama Your issue is caused by `AddDefaultIdentity` will override the cookies configuration, you could check more details from [Failed Authorization doesn't redirect to tenant's login page #78](https://github.com/Finbuckle/Finbuckle.MultiTenant/issues/78)